# Return count zero if null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway to return 0 when `count` for a specific column is `null`. I want to return **zero** when the `count` of `client_order_id` is **null** instead of the query returning 1.

```
  select * from data

  client_id            client_order_id
    1                       222
    1                       222
    1                       333
    2                       444
    2                       555
    3
    4
```

What I have tried:

```
select client_id,count(distinct client_order_id) as count_of_orders from data
group by client_id
   
 client_id            client_order_id
     1                      2 
     2                      2
     3                      1   
     4                      1
```

Requested: Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
 client_id            client_order_id
     1                      2 
     2                      2
     3                      0  
     4                      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
select client_id, count(distinct client_order_id) as count_of_orders
from data
group by client_id;
```

should be doing what you want.  If `client_order_id` is `NULL`, then the value should be `0`.

So, what looks like a `NULL` value is not a `NULL` value.  This could occur if the column were a string and the value the empty string.  If that is the case, you can use `nullif()`:

```
select client_id, count(distinct nullif(client_order_id, '')) as count_of_orders
from data
group by client_id;
```